# Using ForeignCollections in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I want to write a unit test that basically verifies an object I add to a foreign collection actually gets saved and retrieved correctly when the DAO saves retrieves the object
Here is my Entity.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Question implements Question, Serializable {

    @DatabaseField
    private String questionText;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Answer> answers;

    public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
        answers.add(answer);
    }
```

What I want to do is create a `Question` instance add an `Answer` object to the collection and pass the `Question` to my DAO which will persist it.  The persistence works fine on regular fields so I know there is no problem there.

How do I go about adding an `Answer` to the collection?  When I create the `Question` it's answers collection is null. Is it what I have to save the new `Question` and then retrieve it in order for the answers collection to be non null?  Or, do I set the answers to a BaseCollection, LazyCollection instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a FAQ.  The right way to do it is to make use of the [Dao.getEmptyForeignCollection(...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getEmptyForeignCollection%28java.lang.String%29) method to create a collection that you can add items to.  Something like:

```
Question question = new Question();
query.answers = questionDao.getEmptyForeignCollection("answers");
Answer answer1 = new Answer();
query.answers.add(answer1);
// this can come before the question.answers.add()
questionDao.create(question);
```

Comment: Hi Gray, please clarify if the create(question) need to be call before to add some object to the answers collection or is fine to call the create after.

Comment: @Gray i tried your above example and the Question.id is 0 (zero) in database.

Is it posible to store correctly an entity with items added to ForeignCollections from start?